# space of essentially bounded measurable functions on the unit circle

Tags: functional-analysis

Why the set $A =\{ \phi \in L^{\infty}(S):\phi\text{ is invertible in }L^{\infty}(S)\}$ is dense in $L^{\infty}(S)$? Here $S$ is the unit circle in the complex plane. $L^{\infty}(S)$ is the space of all essentially bounded complex valued measurable functions on $S$.
I know that this is true but I am looking for its proof.

Comment: do you mean injective or invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in L^\infty$. For simplicity of the argument we fix some measurable and bounded representant of this class and denote it also with $f$. Define:
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}f(x) & |f(x)|>\frac1n \\ \frac1n & |f(x)|\leq\frac1n \end{cases}$$
This construction remains measurable, as you can check and $\|f_n\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty + \frac1n$, ie $f_n\in L^\infty$.

By definition $|f_n(x)| \ge \frac1n$ for all $x$ so $f_n$ is invertible in $L^\infty$ with $\|f_n^{-1}\|_\infty \leq n$. Further it is obvious again from construction that $\|f_n -f \|_\infty \leq \frac1n$, so the sequence converges to $f$ in $L^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Comment: Can you please elaborate upon the measurability of functions $f_n$s ? Thanks.

Comment: For $U\subset \Bbb R$ let $U_n:= \begin{cases} f^{-1}([-\frac1n,\frac1n]) & \frac1n \in U\\ \emptyset & \frac1n\notin U\end{cases}$, which is a measurable set. Then:
$$f_n^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(U \cap (\Bbb R-[-\frac1n,\frac1n])) \cup U_n$$
If $U$ is measurable then the first set in this union is also measurable, so $f_n$ is a measurable function.

Comment: Thanks. It helps. I have just replaced the interval $[ \frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ by closed unit ball , $\overline{B}(0, \frac{1}{n})$ in the argument since I am considering complex valued functions.